# convert web.config <requestLimits> code to htaccess for uploading multiple files with large size

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config

**I want to upload multiple files in PHP(approx 30-35)**

**Each file size in 2-2.5MB**

I set this live demo which is on IIS Server and now i want to set it in my real project which uses Linux server.

*I try many solutions on StackOverflow but i am not able to find a solution regarding this.*

I try with this code :

```
        ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '300M');
        ini_set('post_max_size', '300M');
        ini_set('memory_limit', '300M');
        ini_set('max_input_time', '900');
        ini_set('max_execution_time', '900');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_FILES);
        sleep(10);
        $total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
        for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
          $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
          if ($tmpFilePath != ""){          
            $newFilePath = "./assets/del/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
              echo "ok"."==";
            }
            sleep(1);
          }
        }
```

But it gives me error like this :

> HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
>
> configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.The request filtering module is

So, i put this code in web.config :

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
     </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

**I want to set above code in .htaccess then how can i do that?**

I tried to set this code in .htaccess BUT NOT WORK

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 300M
php_value upload_max_filesize 300M
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value max_execution_time 900
php_value max_input_time 900
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

**Note :** Without `requestFiltering` code i can not upload large number of files with maximum size on IIS server